# Throwing specific error messages in PLSQL Oracle...catching in hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, plsql

Is it possible to throw a specific error message in a PL/SQL oracle stored procedure and catch it in Hibernate when it gets invoked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can throw user-defined error messages from PL/SQL code. Error codes between -20000 until -20999 are reserved for user specified error messages.

You do so by calling the `raise_application_error` function within your PL/SQL:

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Your error code message here');
```

This will be propagated just like normal Oracle errors.

**Edit:**

I am not a user of Hibernate, but I found this while trying to find an answer and I think it will lead you down the right path.

```
try 
{
    // some hibernate calls
} 
catch (GenericJdbcException ge) 
{
    if(ge.getCause() != null && ge.getCause() instanceof SQLException) 
    {
        SQLException se = (SQLException)ge.getCause();

        // *****************************************************************
        // NOTE: THIS will be where you check for your customer error code.
        // *****************************************************************
        if(se.getErrorCode() == -20001) 
        {
            // your error handling for this case
        }
        else
        {
            throw ge; // do not swallow unhandled exceptions
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw ge // do not swallow unhandled exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I catch that in hibernate?

Comment: `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJdbcException` is an hibernate exception (https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/exception/GenericJDBCException.html). Just catch it.

Comment: nice Job RC, that should be enuogh

Answer (score 0):

you can use output parameter on the pl/sql and pick output in your code using ParameterMode.OUT

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure proc ( pls_out_put out number);

//call output

```
 query.registerStoredProcedureParameter( "pls_out_put", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);`
```

int result = (Integer) query.getOutputParameterValue("pls_out_put");

```
    if (result==1){
     message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "user defined message", "user defined message");

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    } else if(result==0) {
         message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "User defined message", "user defined message");

         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
```