# Display string from raise_application_error in java program

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

I am raising some application errors from PL/SQL procedures. I am setting some messages for instance,

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'message');
```

Is there any way, I can display `'message'` in exception section in catch block of java program from which I called this procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing `catch (Exception e)`, `message` should be available from `e.getMessage()`.

If you're doing `catch (SQLException e)` (or whatever the exception type is for your data access package) `message` should still be available from `e.getMessage()`. Additionally, the `-20001` should come through in `e.getErrorCode()`. Note that it may come through as the absolute value (`20001` as opposed to `-20001`); you'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post will help you out: [Error catching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544035/throwing-specific-error-messages-in-plsql-oracle-catching-in-hibernate)

```
catch (GenericJdbcException ge) {

IF (se.getErrorCode() == -20001)
```

If your not using Hibernate you might need to change the error type.