# DML PL/SQL Procedure That Notifies a Caller of Non-Existing Record

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

My knowledge of Oracle PL/SQL is limited, but I was wondering if it is possible for a PL/SQL **procedure** to **notify** a caller that, for example, a record it attempted to `UPDATE` does not exist.

A caller can be an application code, like Java/JDBC, but it needs to somehow be notified of such event. PL/SQL procedures (not functions) do not return values. Can `RAISE`ing exceptions in the procedure let the DB management code, i.e. JDBC, know that such event has occurred? Are there better solutions out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notification implies something asynchronous to me, but I don't think that's what you mean here - the caller is handling the response, right? Raising an exception is the way to notify a caller that a problem occurred.

JDBC would get an SQLException, for example. The exception you raise (which can be your own, [with `raise_application_error()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#i1871)) will have a number and a message which will be available from the SQLException, as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16281654/266304).

You can check the [`SQL%ROWCOUNT` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHJJJDG) to check whether an update affected any rows, and raise an exception if the value of that is zero - indicating no rows were updated, so the record you're trying to update doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an out parameter on your procedure, where you could return the count of updated rows (using SQL%ROWCOUNT), so the caller would know if 0 records were updated.